# Display mod_wsgi error on webpage

Tags: mod-wsgi, error-reporting

I have set up mod_wsgi to serve python files. Indeed it does.

However, if i have syntax errors on the .py file (such as indentation errors), i get a Server Error when the page loads, and have to go to the log to see why the error occurred (ie, indentation)

Is it possible to have mod_wsgi display the error on the page (at least for dev environment)?

Something similar to php's error_reporting options, perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completely. The closest you can get is:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Error_Catching_Middleware

This will only do it for errors which occur during execution of a request which are actually propagated up to the WSGI server level.

It will not work for errors in the loading of the WSGI sript itself, or in cases where a framework is being used and the framework itself catches the errors and turns then into 500 pages. In the latter, the framework usually has a means of enabling a debug page.

Now, it sounds like you are not using a framework but are writing raw WSGI scripts. If you are new to Python web programming writing raw WSGI is not recommended. So, go use a framework instead and it should provide you what you want as a feature.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of work (and many thanks to other Stack Overflow contributors!) you can get good error information to the browser. Your WSGI "root" sits within the "application" definition, of course:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    import linecache, sys
    try:
        from cgi import parse_qs, escape      # Application starts here
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html'),]) #to here
        return ["Whatever application wants to say."] 

    except:                                   # Error output starts here
        exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
        f = tb.tb_frame
        lineno = tb.tb_lineno
        filename = f.f_code.co_filename
        linecache.checkcache(filename)
        line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
        es = '''Error in {}, Line {} "{}": {}'''.format(filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj)
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html'),])
        return [es]
```